# Pexpect.before out of syncc

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I collect some data from users' routers, connecting via SSH, reading from pexpect. before.

Having trouble on only one router, that his Pexpect output is out of sync. I have 16 parameters that need collecting data from the router.

Solution from @user145078:

```
session.send(cmd)
index = session.expect([cmd, pexpect.TIMEOUT], 1)
session.send('\n')
index = session.expect([whatever you expect])
```

Worked a little bit, from 16 parameters, 14 are now in sync, and 2 of them aren't.

I don't know why those 2 parameters are still out of sync. Data is gathered in alphabetical order, meaning if I have commands for 'router_speed', 'signal_to_noise_ratio', 'serial', 'device_uptime','attn' they would be gathered in order:

'attn'
'device_uptime'
'router_speed'
'serial'
'SNR'

With the solution I used for this, only 'SNR' and 'attn' parameters are out of sync, with 'SNR' .before outputting last commands output and 'attn' .before outputing welcoming message to router:

> Speedport Plus181\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nBusyBox v1.15.3 () built-in
> shell (ash)\r\nEnter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

Don't know what to do, all those other solutions are a bit complicated to get into my running code.

Sorry for the bad grammar or bad explanation but I need help :D

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it, it was a syntax bug/error in the commands for those two parameters.

> missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 37

All is fine now.